# Unable to view JSP content, getting "an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)"

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, netbeans

I have just started Spring boot app development. I'm trying to show simple jsp page with default jsp file created by `Netbeans 11.1`. I searched this error on the internet and found many questions and answers on the internet that I have tried so far.
Most of the answers say this error is caused by not having `controller file` in the same directory as other java files. But that is not my case. First check out my file structure below.
[image]

I have tried to load `home.jsp` file directly from `webapp` folder than from `webapp/WEB-INF` folder and than `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp` folder as I see this structure from the demo app from Github.

I have added jasper dependency inside `.pom` file which is responsible to loading .jsp content.

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
         <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
         <!--<version>9.0.24</version>-->
</dependency>
```

Here is my AppContoller class code

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("home")
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("HomeController is running!!!"); //showing this output
        return "home.jsp";
    }
}
```

**Note:** This class show the "HomeController is running!!!" output when I type `locathost:8080/home` **That means** the controller is configured correctly and the error is not because of different paths.

My `MyWebAppApplication` class has nothing but the default main method.
This is what I get in the browser.

> **Whitelabel Error Page**
>   This application has no explicit mapping for
>    /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Sep 10 15:38:44 PKT 2019
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). /home.jsp

If anything else I have to include in question let me know.

I'm using

- Window 10
- Netbeans 11.1
- Java version 8
- Spring Boot with Maven
- Embeded Tomcat server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `Netbeans 11.1` generate jsp file with these two line

```
<%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
```

here the prefix is `f` and uri is `http://java.sun.com/jsf/core`. when I replaced this taglib to

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>   //here prefix is `c` 
                                                                  & uri is from jsp/jstl instead of jsf
```

And commented out the second taglib from default jsp file, It worked for me :).
I supposed these dependencies should do the work but we have to specify the correct tablib in jsp page too.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also now I'm returning `home` in the controller instead of `home.jsp` as suggested by i.bondarenko in his answer.
Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Replace `return "home.jsp";` with `return "home";`

Also you should add some config properties and dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Update:**
Use following class to run the app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyWebAppApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoMvcApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyWebAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried these things but still getting the same output in console and browser is showing `/WEB-INF/home.jsp` instead of `/home.jsp` at last line.

Comment: Sorry missed the path:
`spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/`
replase with `spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp`

Comment: getting this `/WEB-INF/jsphome.jsp`. I think there should be `/` at the end of jsp path.

Comment: with `/WEB-INF/jsphome.jsp/` i'm getting "The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsf/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application"

Comment: Add "/" at the end "spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp"
You do not need to deploy this jar to tomcat. Spring boot has embedded tomcat.

Comment: have a look at the update in my answer, please.
Run it as simple java application

Comment: I have just created simple app. You could clone it and merge pom.xml and controller https://github.com/ivan333m/spring-boot-jsp.git use http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: I solved the problem with your helpful answer and some other modifications. plus one for that